# Unable to use created element with jquery

Tags: jquery, element

I'm new in jquery and I suffer from a problem which is a little strange.
After creating a div in jquery,I can't use it,this example will show you how is the problem!
let's assume that in the get.php page there is just:echo "test test";
the code in my file :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("#bda").click(function()
{
$.post("get.php",function(data){
$("#tdiv").append('<div class="info" >'+data +'</div>');
});     
});

$(".info").click(function()
{
  alert("done");
});
});
</script>     
</head>

<body>
 <div id="bda">click here</div>
 <div align="center" style="border:1px solid blue" id="tdiv">    
  example
 </div>
<div class="info" >it works here</div>
```

Can some one help me..

Comment: what exactly is the problem, whats happening? what have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: Can you alert(data)..ur able to successful get the data? "after creation a div in jquery,i can't use it" ,by use what you meant? what you wanted to do and that is not getting done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What jQuery does with `$(".info")` is selecting the `.info` elements at the time you call it - which is only one element since the other one is appended later (through ajax). That other element therefore has no click event attached. So, the `.info` selector is not actually saved - merely the elements are pulled out of the document and then the selector is discarded.

What you want is that jQuery checks element against a selector *when you click*. You can do that with event delegation:

```
// When you click somewhere in the body, jQuery will check whether you
// clicked on a `.info` element and execute the function in that case.
// This also works for elements added later on.

$("body").on("click", ".info", function() { ... });
```

Comment: I used your solution,but it doesn't work:
"Object doesn't support this property or method"
another question:is it really pratically to use $("body")?
if the page is charged ?
Thank you

Comment: @nabilmenzel: Try `.delegate` if you're using an older version of jQuery. You should bind the event to the closest persistent parent. In your case that closest parent is the body - what would you like to bind the event to instead?

Comment: I use the latest version of jQuery,i tryed to use .delegate but nothing's matter :S

Comment: @nabil menzel: What does `$.fn.jquery` return?

Comment: 1.3.2 !
but i don't what it means

Comment: @nabil menzel: That means you're using jQuery 1.3.2 which is **not** the latest version. It's more than 3 years old in fact. Try using version 1.7.2 instead.

Comment: Sorry,I was confused, i thought i have the latest version !!!
Really very sorry to disturb you.

Answer (score 1):

as you insert new element to the DOM, you should delegate the event:

```
$("body").on('click', '.info', function() {
  alert("done");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you bind the click event to info classes at the execution of the script but you add the new div later during the ajax process. you have to reassign the click event to this class

try not binding with .click(), use .on() instead, like mentioned here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$("body").on('click', '.info', function() {
  alert("done");
});
```